# Accessibility issue for custom buttons made from SVGs

Tags: react-native, accessibility

I'm trying to add accessibility to my app (disclosure, using 0.59.8 version of RN). I have SVG images (each in separate TSX files, called like "IconClose") that  I am using to make custom buttons. When I call these SVGs, I wrap them in a TouchableOpacity with style and an onPress to make them act as buttons.  I tried adding an accessibilityLabel="close button" and setting the accessibilityRole and the accessibilityTraits to the TouchableOpacity. They work as buttons and do the navigation perfectly, however when I check the accessibility, I can tap on the button to select it, but I get nothing as far as the voice reader in iOS saying the label or the hint. I've tried wrapping it in a View, I tried adding titles and aria-label to the SVG. Is there a way to make these custom buttons voice reader accessible?

the IconClose button

```js
import React from 'react';
import Svg, { Path } from 'svgs';

export const IconClose = (props: any) => (
  <Svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="#000000" {...props} >
    <Path
      d="M13.4 12l6.3-6.3c.4-.4.4-1 0-1.4s-1-.4-1.4 0L12 10.6 5.7 4.3c-.4-.4-1-.4-1.4 0s-.4 1 0 1.4l6.3 6.3-6.3 6.3c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.4.2.2.4.3.7.3s.5-.1.7-.3l6.3-6.3 6.3 6.3c.2.2.5.3.7.3s.5-.1.7-.3c.4-.4.4-1 0-1.4L13.4 12z"
      fill="#231f20"
    />
  </Svg>
);
```

where I call the button

```js
export const Page: FC<IPageProps> = ({ imageSource, location, title, info, actions, content, footer, onCloseButtonPress }) => {
  const renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.header}>
        {imageSource 
          ? <Image style={styles.image} source={imageSource} />
          : <IconImage width={120} height={120} fill={COLORS.TECH_GRAY} />
        }
        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={styles.closeIcon}
          onPress={onCloseButtonPress} 
          activeOpacity={0.8}
          accessibilityComponentType="button" 
          accessibilityLabel="close">
            <IconClose/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `accessibilityRole="button"`? Also, according to the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.html), you may need to use `accessibilityLabel`, not `accessibleLabel`.

Comment: Yes, I've tried both those. Sorry about the typo on the accessibiltyLabel. I will fix the question.